# callablestatement not returning resultset via java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have in a situation where I need to fetch resultset from MySQL database. But the problem is that when I'm using prep/callable statement, I'm not getting resultset but when the same sql query is run via toad or phpmyadmin, its giving proper and expected result on console. The code is as below:-

```
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    String mappedEVentIds = "";
    try {
        connection = CreateDBConnection.createDBConn();
        cstmt = connection.prepareCall("select metaEventId from metatologtable where metatologtable.baseEventId in (select `metatologtable`.baseEventId from metatologtable inner join logtable on logtable.baseEventId = metatologtable.baseEventId where metatologtable.metaEventId In"+metaEventIds+")");
        ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            mappedEVentIds = mappedEVentIds+rs.getString("metaEventId");

        }
        return mappedEVentIds;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    finally{
        closeConnection(connection, cstmt);
    }
```

It's not throwing any error, but resultset in empty and doesn't come in while(rs.next) block

Comment: catch block is empty.add `e.printStackTrace()` to print if a error occured

Comment: This code is under process and the catch block will be containing further codes and actions to be followed in case of exception. But the main problem is of the values that why the same is coming via DB but not via java.

Comment: This `catch(Exception e){}` is a very serious offence in many development houses. Expect an official reprimand if you ever commit code to the VCS with an empty catch block. **never have an empty catch block**. You are swallowing the error and then asking us to guess what it might be.

Comment: Further, it is now 2015. Java 7 was released in 2011. There is absolutely no excuse, 4 years later, to use `try...finally` instead of `try-with-resources`.

Comment: I'm sorry if that is cofusing you, but the catch block will be calling a method followed by logging the error. As I said that code is in draft mode and trust me, its not throwing any error and exiting from the method properly.

Comment: And you have SQL `String` concatenation in your code. This block of code is simply a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: You are ignoring exceptions. Do you get any exceptions? The `CallableStatement` is for executing stored procedures. Technically normal statements should also work from a specification perspective, but have you tried with a prepared statement (`prepareStatement`) instead?